# Drawing frequently updated Graphics inside a complex Swing UI without blocking Event Dispatch Thread

Tags: java, performance, swing, graphics

I'm developing a plugin for an old application that uses the Swing UI toolkit. As far as I know, Swing's philosophy is that everything executes on the Event Dispatch Thread. I need to integrate a JPanel where it repaint()s itself every 16ms.

I think this will cause the EDT to be flooded with redrawing that JPanel and making other events wait longer, (mentioned in the Javadocs) which could slow down the app. I'm already seeing slowdowns in a test instance of the application.

The way I see it now there are 2 solutions:

- Render everything to an image, then render that to the screen, this way, long computations can be rendered by a background thread and the EDT takes care of drawing a simple image, reducing latency.
- Make repaint calls only when the user is actually doing something.

*What is a performant way to draw dynamic, frequently-updated content inside a Swing UI without blocking the EDT and the rest of the UI?*

Comment: The answer "depends".  As you say, if the computational time is to long, then using a Swing `Timer` might not be suitable, in that case you should consider using a `SwingWorker`

Comment: I could use a SwingWorker to continually pre-render the image. Is that what you mean? @MadProgrammer

Comment: That's one approach, by creating the "frames" in the `SwingWorker`, you can have the component paint them when `process` is called, the problem is, what happens if the worker is producing more frames than the UI can consume, do you drop them?  Do you cache them?  These are questions you need to be able to answer with some confidence

Answer (score 0):

The animation, processing changes painting complex modelling objects on a Graphics/Graphics2D can indeed be separated. Whether SwingWorker, SwingTimer, event driven.

You can use a `BuffferedImage` with `getGraphics` and at the end of `Graphics2D` drawing do a `disposeGraphics`. Take a compatible image type as the `Graphics` of the screen.

Then the actual painting will just do a `drawImage` in the `paintComponent` update event handling.

Log processing times, and repaints - for optimization. This profiling is crucial to knowing performance bottlenecks.

Often costly things can be improved. Like using *affine transformations*, preloaded images of course, and so on. Like doing light-weight drawing instead of tiny JComponent hierarchies. Like pruning invisible parts.